# Export a Unity container information to xml configuration

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

In Microsoft Unity you can configure a container from an existing XML configuration but is there a way to do the opposite? From an initialized container export the corresponding XML configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After "diving" the Unity source code my conclusion is it ain't possible for now.